# Hibernate JPA - StackOverflowException - JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting an error using the following classes. I wrote `AuditTrail` myself according to the `Sale` class. Although when I'm trying to create an AuditTrail I get a `StackOverflowException`, what am I doing wrong here?

I'ts referencing that `ticket_account_id` doesn't exist on `Sale`.

```
...
import registration.Account;
import sales.Sale;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuditTrail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="audit_sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        ,
        @JoinColumn(name="audit_account_id", referencedColumnName = "ticket_account_id")
    })
    private Sale sale;

    @Autowired
    public AuditTrail(Sale sale) {
        this.sale = sale;
    }
}
```

And the Sale class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sale implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id")
        ,
        @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_concert_id", referencedColumnName = "concert_id")})
    private Ticket ticket;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date sellDate;

    @Min(1)
    private int price;

}
```

And the Ticket class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@IdClass(TicketId.class)
public class Ticket implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="concert_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Concert concert;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account account;

}
```

### Error

```
2017-05-24 10:56:05.150 ERROR 138416 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@59717824] to prepare test instance [nl.first8.hu.ticketsale.sales.TicketRepositoryIntegrationTest@36d582cb]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ticket_account_id in sale
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ticket_account_id in sale
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:854) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Database structure:
[image]

Comment: You have a 1-1 to Sale supposedly with 2 FK columns yet Sale has a single PK field, so you can only ever have 1 FK column! Where is this StackOverflowException ? you know the thing you reference in the title but don't post (or its stack trace)

Comment: @NeilStockton Added the stacktrace, beginner with hibernate so I don't know exactly what you mean about the FK columns and PK columns. Should I add both the FK columns in `AuditTrail`?

Comment: Okay but `Account` is bound to `Sale` and I would like to store `account_id` and the `sale_id` how can I manage this with only 1 `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: i want to store the account_id in AuditTrail as well as the sale_id, but the Sale has a relation to Ticket which has a relation to the Account (as shown in the code). So it does have something to do with their relation sin e I want to retrieve 2 properties from Sale, the id and the ticket_account_id (as shown in the code)

Comment: A "Sale" is represented by its "id", It is a Long. An "Account" several relations away is of no relevance in identifying a Sale object. As said, go back to documentation

Comment: Aaah okay I see, because the Ticket has both properties annotated as Id, this is possible there but not the way I'm currently doing it to Sale, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical
>   name: ticket_account_id in sale

Says it all. Your Entity classes don't match your database tables.
Fix that.

Comment: added in the Database structure. I do have a column called `ticket_account_id` in `sale` in both my database and my class